# Hide field in report depending on sub string value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have parameter in my stored procedure `@Selection nvarchar` that can hold string values. So I will pass in that parameter something like 'Today,yesterday,last week'. In the stored procedure, I make sub strings from that parameter and put them into a temp table and make same field hiding. And it works.

But I don't know how to hide fields in ssrs on the same way like in stored procedure. I will put value in that parameter and for example I will want to hide/show some field based on that value.

So if I have value 'Today,yesterday,last week', I would like to hide 3 fields, first one will depends on today value, second on yesterday and last one on last week.

Comment: You are not going to get any help on this without including a lot more info on your SQL scripts and screenshots of your SSRS report design.

Answer (score 0):

You can set column visibility depending on your parameter value. To set column visibility, right-click on column handle and choose Column visibility.
[image]

Value for expression should be like this:

```
=IIf(InStr(Parameters!Days, "yesterday") > 0, True, False)
```

Where `Parameters!Days` is your parameter, and `yesterday` is appropriate key for each column you would like to be dynamically hidden.

Also, if you do not select this columns in your SQL code (i.e. for one case returned columns could be (Yesterday, Today), while for another (Today, Total)) you can then use built in feature of dataset to determine if column is missing in data sent from SQL Server. Expression for visibility then will be:

```
=Fields!SomeColumn.IsMissing
```